# How to Extract the information about UI elements during runtime of an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

Is there any way that one could extract the information about UI elements (of the `UIView`) from the application’s memory during runtime of an iOS application (iPhone). Like getting a reference to the current `UIView` element and find a way to enumerate all UI elements contained in that view and create an abstract graph of the `UIView` calls of the app dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you may be interested n some general suggestions, I'll give you this one: look at DCIntrospect ([available on github, with good documentation](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect)).

With this open source software, you can examine any item in your UI that subclasses UIView. You can see its many properties in your console.

It is very easy to use. I tried it, and it was a very simple add to my application delegate. To enable it, you press the space bar on your keyboard.

Since it is open source, you can examine the code and see for yourself what UI element properties are available and even make changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

UIView comes with an undocumented function to do that:  -recursiveDescription.  It's not as pretty as DCIntrospect, but you don't have to add anything to your project.  Simply do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [view recursiveDescription]);
```

or you can call it from the debugger:

```
p [view recursiveDescription]
```

See Apple's [Technical Note 2239](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) (scroll to the bottom) for more details, and other interesting debugging commands.